# Force to step down atomic level of an electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals

How much force is needed to step down atomic level of an electron? Where does it gets it energy to overcome the orbits to step up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As G. Smith has explained this *seemingly* happens on its own and that process is called spontenous emission. That is correct in the sense that you don't need other atoms or agents around for this and certainly don't need to subject the atom to any additional field. But for the benefit of other readers however I will like to further elaborate on how this happens as it does not happen on its own.

We cannot explain spontenous emission using classical EM theory and simple quantum mechanics alone. The most satisfactory explanation comes from QED --our current best theory for electromagentism. According to QED, the electromagnetic field has a ground state called QED vacuum. This QED vacuum is present everywhere. The excited electron state is a stationary state of the nucleus + electron system but is not when you add the QED vacuum to the mix. You now have two types of possibilities:

1. Electron + Atom system in excited state.
2. Electron + Atom in one of the lower states with one or more photons in one or more of the transition frequencies of the atom.

This interaction is fundamentally electromagentic and that is why photons emerge in this picture (as opposed to say gluons). If you represent the above states as a wavefunction and solve for the probabilities of each of these states then you will find that the second types of states are more probable.

You should ask now why the reverse interaction does not happen spontenously as well. The simple explanation for this is that the probability for the reverse interaction is almost zero. That is because the EM field itself has infintely many degrees of freedom. So the photons emitted by the spontaneous emission have inifinite ways to interact and the probality of the one particular case where they excite the very atom that emitted them is practically zero.

This answers the second part of your question. It does not get the energy to "overcome the orbit" (as you called it) on its own or the QED vacuum. It has to be supplied to it in the form of incident photons.

A more detailed and technical explanation can be found in [this paper](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.13886) (paywalled unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

No force is required. Atoms in excited states undergo a process called “spontaneous emission” in which the electron emits one (or, less likely, more than one) photon at the same time that it transitions to a lower energy level. The photon carries away the difference in energy between the higher orbital and the lower one.

The opposite process also occurs: An electron can absorb a photon and transition to an excited state in a higher orbital. The incident photon provides the required energy.

Comment: But isn't that an EM interaction fundamentally?

Comment: Yes, the electromagnetic interaction of electrons and photons is what makes spontaneous emssion happen. But you don’t have to apply an external EM field to an atom to get it to transition from a higher energy state to a lower energy state. It does so on its own, spontaneously. This is why I said no force is required.

Comment: If you mean an external force then yes. But such an interaction can only happen in an electron that is bound in a potential already. Which means fundamentally the forces that are involved are that of the proton from the nucleus and that from the ground state of EM field itself. Now, there is no such thing as a force in QED but given OP's meaning that is what technically is happening here. Right?

Comment: Yes, but I don’t think this is what the OP was asking.